# Powershell addition not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying a simple powershell program. But for some reason its not working. Can someone help me with this?

Ex:-

Script:-

```
function Add-Numbers($a,$b) {
    return $a + $b
}
Add-Numbers $a $b
```

When I try to run this on the powershell cmd, I dont get any output.

But if I modify this a little bit (as below), it works fine.

Script:-

```
param($a,$b)

function Add-Numbers($a,$b) 
{
    return $a + $b
}
Add-Numbers $a $b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the Add-Numbers with some actual values:

```
function Add-Numbers($a,$b) {
    $a + $b
}
Add-Numbers 1 2
```

Will return `3`.

If you want to execute the `ps1` and pass values to it, you have write the `Param` block in the first line:

```
param($a,$b)

function Add-Numbers($a,$b) 
{
    $a + $b
}
Add-Numbers $a $b
```

Now you can invoke the script with two values. Note: You will invoke the `ps1` file, not the name of the function you defined (the whole script gets executed).

Comment: I trying to pass commands from the cmd line. Like .\Add-Numbers 1 2 from the cmd line..